# Vim-Latex: Double-Quote Automatically Replaced

Tags: vim

I use Vim with Vim-Latex plugin to edit my LaTeX documents. I have the problem that whenever I want to insert a double quote ("), it automatically get replace by (``). Any idea how can I disable that while still having Vim-Latex enabled?

Comment: Try pressing `"` twice in a row, that should give you back the non-smart quote...

Comment: Nope, this does not work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `let g:Tex_SmartKeyQuote=0` to `$VIM/ftplugin/tex.vim` (create that file if necessary), where $VIM corresponds to ~/.vim for unixy operating systems and ~/vimfiles for Windows.

There are more configuration variables, see [the latexsuite manual](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-latex-suite.html).

Comment: Thanks man. But to be honest, I liked it that it replaces " with ``, but the thing is that I wanted to disable it because it would do that even in comments. Is there anyway around that?! That is, keep it enabled, but disable it when I want with a short-cut key or something like that.

Comment: I don't know. Actually, I would recommend to use `\enquote` from the `csquotes` package instead of `` and ''.

Comment: You can always use `CTRL+V"` to insert `"` without expansion. See `:he i_CTRL-V` for details.

Comment: @Aditya That should probably be an answer, since it addresses his problem perfectly. I think it's exactly what he was looking for since he specifically asked for a "short-cut key".

Comment: Pasting a " still expanded to ``, but if you first do `setl paste`, the double quote will be pasted as intended.

Answer (score 9):

I usually type `\"`, since in that context the `"` is not replaced by "smart quotes," and then delete the `\`. This is convenient enough for me, since I rarely need the `"` character, and I don't want to change Vim-LaTeX's default behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I know you already accepted an answer, but just for those who use vim for LaTeX, but (like me) don't use the Vim-LaTeX plugin, I use the following, which I put inside my personal $HOME/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim. It handles quotation marks pretty well (at least for my purposes), and deactivates itself in comments and following \. I began with some code from the ["auctex.vim"](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=162) plugin, but have I have added a lot to it and customized it a lot myself.

```
" Function for smart-quotes: double
function! s:TexQuotes()
    if getline('.')[0:col(".")] =~ '\(^\|[^\\]\)%'
       let kinsert = "\""
    else
        let kinsert = "\'\'"
        let left = getline('.')[col('.')-2]
        if left =~ '^\(\|\s\|{\|(\|\[\|&\)$'
            let kinsert = "\`\`"
        elseif left == "\\"
            let kinsert = "\""
        endif
    endif
    return kinsert
endfunction
" mapping for quotation marks
inoremap <buffer> " <C-R>=<SID>TexQuotes()<CR>
" Function for smart-quotes: single
function! s:TexSingQuotes()
    if getline('.')[0:col(".")] =~ '\(^\|[^\\]\)%'
       let schminsert = "'"
    else
        let schminsert = "'"
        let left = getline('.')[col('.')-2]
        if left =~ '^\(\|\s\|{\|(\|\[\|&\)$'
            let schminsert = '`'
        endif
    endif
    return schminsert
endfunction
" mapping for single quotation mark
inoremap <buffer> ' <C-R>=<SID>TexSingQuotes()<CR>
```

This could probably be cleaned up a bit. I wrote it when I was first learning the tiny bit of vimscript language that I know.

You could probably use it *alongside* the vim-latex plugin, so long as you disable its smart-quote feature, but I haven't tried.